# WordPress Multisite subpages of Main Site redirect to Front Page when accessed with non www

Tags: wordpress, redirect, multisite, no-www

I already checked quite a few different threads here, but I wasn't able to find a solution there.
I'm running a WordPress Multisite and there is a problem with the following redirects:

```
https://example.com/site1 -> Redirects to font page https://www.example.com/
example.com/site1 -> Redirects to font page https://www.example.com/
```

So the problem is trying to access the site with non-www. The thing is, that also the subpages have to be accessible with non www as much as www, so what should happen is:

`https://example.com/site1 -> Redirects to font page https://www.example.com/site1` 
etc.

There are also subsites with subdomains, but they work with www and non-www all the same.

I already tried different approaches with
`define('NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'https://www.example.com');`
because before it was redirecting to /wp-signup.php?new=example.com which I at least got rid of by adding the NOBLOGREDIRECT.

Thank you all in advance!